# Passing UITextField text to UILabel on different View Controller

Tags: ios, segue

I am trying to pass UITextField's text from View Controller 1 to the UILabel in View Controller 2.

I am using segue to pass the information, but I am not getting anything on Label. It seems like the text from the text field becomes `NULL` in when it is passed to view controller 2.

**View Controller 1 (UITextField)**

```
- (IBAction)sendtoVC2:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toVC2" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toVC2"])
    {
        ViewController2 *VC2 = (ViewController2 *)segue.destinationViewController;
        VC2.label.text = self.textField.text;
    }
}
```

**View Controller 2.h (UILabel)**

```
#import "ViewController1.h"

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, it happens because the label doesn't exist yet. When UIViewController is created, its view is not loaded until it is actually required. This is called 'lazy loading', which means that a value is created only when somebody requires it for the first time.

> Lazy loading is a design pattern commonly used in computer programming
>   to defer initialization of an object until the point at which it is
>   needed. It can contribute to efficiency in the program's operation if
>   properly and appropriately used.

Your UILabel property in second view controller gets a value only after second view controller's view is loaded, which happens only when somebody explicitly calls its 'view' property. So, to prove my theory just insert one more line:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toVC2"])
{
    ViewController2 *VC2 = (ViewController2 *)segue.destinationViewController;
    UIView *unusedReferenceToViewToLoadTheView = VC2.view
    VC2.label.text = self.textField.text;
}
```

Comment: You are awesome! It worked! But, how can I remove this unused variable warning?

Comment: If I recall correctly, then putting __unused before a variable will silence your warning, like `__unused UIView *unusedReferenceToViewToLoadTheView = VC2.view`

Comment: It's better to take a NSString variable in Second vc and assign text to that.
And in view did load of Second VC assign the text variable to label.
Because it's not recommended to Modify the view of another view controller directly (VC2) from VC1. 
It's against MVC pattern.

Comment: @TechGeek_iOS Agree, and another good addition would be to modify NSString setter so that it would check if viewIsLoaded() and then set the value to label. But, http://i.imgur.com/X9JYVgw.png

Answer (score 2):

In viewDidLoad of View Controller 2, the text is lost, because the label was not created yet.

You have to save the text in a variable, and in viewDidLoad of ViewController2, set the text in label.

Like this:

**View Controller 1:**

```
 - (IBAction)sendtoVC2:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toVC2" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toVC2"])
    {
        ViewController2 *VC2 = (ViewController2 *)segue.destinationViewController;
        VC2.text = self.textField.text;
    }
}
```

**View Controller 2.h:**

```
 #import "ViewController1.h"

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *text;
@end
```

**View Controller 2.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    label.text = text;
}
```

Comment: Your answer works too, but I will have to go with @xinatanil answer because I don't need to create unnecessary `NSString`s. Good answer though.

Comment: It's better to take a NSString variable in Second vc and assign text to that. And in view did load of Second VC assign the text variable to label. Because it's not recommended to Modify the view of another view controller directly (VC2) from VC1. It's against MVC pattern.